# iOS SDK: Launch the Camcorder (video camera), not the still camera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, video

I'm using the following code to launch the still camera on the iPhone.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
picker.delegate = self; 
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

I'm wondering how I can launch only the video camera, and not the still camera. I need [this view](http://www.cl.ly/0x0F323n0L221T2y362C) without the switch in the bottom right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You will have to add these two lines to launch in video camera mode.

```
picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
```

You can also limit it to the video mode and hide the switch by only enabling the appropriate media type. Do this to allow only video mode,

```
picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
```

You will however need to add `MobileCoreServices.framework` for this and `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
```